# Error when trying to use "traceroute" function from the scapy module in python terminal. OS: ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, scapy, ubuntu-18.04

I typed this on the python terminal:

```
from scapy.all import *
traceroute("gmail.com")
```

Got this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", 
line 1428, in traceroute
    timeout=timeout, filter=filter, verbose=verbose, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", 
line 326, in sr
    s = conf.L3socket(filter=filter, iface=iface, nofilter=nofilter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", 
line 326, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 
socket.htons(type))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 144, in __init__
_socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
    PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I have already tried searching the net for a solution to this but I wasn't sucessful. I'd be glad to receive help on this issue I'm experiencing; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`traceroute` needs to access raw sockets, thus, you need to start python as root as raw sockets are restricted by Linux

Type `sudo python` when starting your shell, or `sudo scapy` (to have scapy pre-configured shell), or if it’s a program file, `sudo python yourprogram.py`

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out by myself before seeing your answer... but your answer is correct.